# Defining Common Stylesheets, JavaScript Across Multiple Razor View Layouts

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-core, .net-5

In my `ASP.NET Core (.NET 5)` application, I have a standard `_Layout.cshtml` that references various stylesheets, and JS scripts.

My **goal** is create *various* `_Layout*` variants that will refer to a single `default` or `master` list of stylesheets and JavaScript references per environment.

The idea is to have a references layout page (AKA RefLayout) that contains only references and no reusable styles. And the actual layout pages like `_Layout.cshtml` and `_LayoutAuthenticated.cshtml`, etc. that refer to `RefLayout` to inherit the stylesheets and scripts.

At the moment, it seems for every layout page I want to use, I have to copy/paste this section which will make adding/removing stylesheets and scripts a maintaining nightmare as the layouts increase.

`_Layout.cshtml` CSS section

```
    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        ... <!--removed all other references for brevity-->
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    ... <!--removed all other references for brevity-->
    </environment>
```

`_Layout.cshtml` Scripts section.

```
<environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
... <!--removed all other references for brevity-->
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
... <!--removed all other references for brevity-->
```

---

Is there a solution to increase the maintainability of these files layout files? If possible, preserving the per environment is a +1.

#### Feel free to also comment suggestions that consider this to not be worth overengineering or leading to a *design smell*.

Comment: Layout's are views, and can also specify a parent layout. So it's easy to have a base layout with base styles / scripts, with sections for child layouts to extend.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RenderSection` to

> render common layouts, shared directives, and run common code before rendering pages and views -- [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Usage:

`RenderSection("developmentscripts", false)`

Defining the `developmentscripts` section

```
@section developmentscripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
}
```